# Specify custom merge message when using git pull

Tags: git, git-pull

Is there a way to specify custom merge message without using --edit?

This brings up editor:

`git pull <some location> --edit`

I would like:

`git pull <some location> --merge-message "Merge from X"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#_description:

`git pull` is shorthand for `git fetch` followed by `git merge`.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt--mltmsggt

`git merge` (and hence `git pull`) accepts `-m message` to pass the message and `-F file` to get the message from the file.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Though I used local repositories so needed to specify FETCH_HEAD as well:

git fetch <PathToOtherRepo> && git merge -m "Merge from other repo" FETCH_HEAD